# how could i catch the MVC3 exception and not return an blank view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception

I want to process the exception in the override method OnException the code like below:
if i set the filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
the return view will show a blank view.
i don't want it redirect to the 500 page.
so how could i do?

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnException(filterContext);

    var exception = new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception);
    if (exception.GetHttpCode() == (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        if (WebConstants.systemHandleExceptionList.Contains(filterContext.Exception.GetType()))
        {
            //process the error
            SaveErrorMessage(filterContext.Exception.GetType().Name);

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //record the unhandle message to log
            errorlog.Error("", filterContext.Exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect it to a different page right after setting the flag to true. See example below

```
RouteValueDictionary errorRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary( new { controller = "Error", action = "Action" } );

filterContext.Result = new ActionRedirectResult( errorRouteValues );
filterContext.Cancel = true;
```

Comment: ActionRedirectResult: it's can't use in MVC3？

Comment: i'm not want redirect to an other page, i just want it came back and get the error show on the paga.

Comment: I'm in the same problem: I wish to stay in the page and show the error with Javascript and/or jQueryUI.